# Laravel Artisan CLI doesn't set the right URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

## Synopsis

I am having a little trouble understanding how `Artisan` works with environments and `.env` files.

My problem is when I generate e-mails from a task on the command line which uses the `url` helper I am unable to generate the correct link.

When I try to run the following commands, my e-mails contain `http://localhost/<link part>` instead of `http://domain.local/`; also I am working locally.

```
php artisan account:probation --method=notify
php artisan --env=production account:probation --method=notify
php artisan --env=local account:probation --method=notify
```

**edit** my database connections are set inside the `.env` and connects because it collects the e-mail address necessary to e-mail to and also the created date/time, whilst not being able to use the `APP_URL` as per the `.env`.

When these same e-mails run via the application they are set correctly with: `http://domain.local/`, so now I am a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `'url'` key in `config/app.php`. This is the value being picked up by Artisan. By default it is set to `'http://localhost'`.

If you would like to specify this value using the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file, you will need to change the `'url'` key in the config file to:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

### Edit

When run via the web, a valid `Request` object is already available. When run via Artisan, Laravel must create a fake `Request` object. It does this using the url defined in the config.

This value is passed to the `create` method on the Symfony `Request` object. This method uses the native `parse_url` method to break the value into url components. If the parsed url does not contain a `host` component, it will default to localhost.

Given a url of `domain.local`, you get the following results:

```
print_r(parse_url('domain.local'));
=====
Array
(
    [path] => domain.local
)
```

Since the components don't include a `host` component, the host will default to localhost.

If, however you used `//domain.local`, you get the following results:

```
print_r(parse_url('//domain.local'));
=====
Array
(
    [host] => domain.local
)
```

Now that the `host` component exists, this will be used for any URL generation required by your Artisan commands.

Source code to look at for more information:

Getting the url from the config and creating the `Request`:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetRequestForConsole.php

The Symfony `Request` being generated (`create` method called above):
https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php

Comment: That is exactly what I have :S

Comment: @Ash This works for me. If you've used `php artisan config:cache`, make sure you clear or re-cache the config after making any changes. Also, make sure your APP_URL value includes the protocol (e.g. starts with `http://`), otherwise it will prepend `http://localhost` to whatever value you set.

Comment: @Ash Another thing to note: if your machine has the $APP_URL environment variable set, this value will take precedence over anything in the .env file.  Specifically, if your $APP_URL variable is set to the empty string, then your url will be set to `http://localhost`. You can check if it is set with this: `if [ -z ${APP_URL+x} ]; then echo 'not set'; else echo 'set'; fi`. You can unset it with this: `unset APP_URL`. (You cannot just do `export APP_URL=`, as that is setting it to the empty string, which is not what you want.)

Comment: When I run that, I get "not set".

Comment: @Ash Did you try `php artisan config:clear` to make sure you're not seeing a cached value?

Comment: Yes. Although where is `$APP_URL` set for CLI use, this I couldn't find.

Comment: @Ash Artisan uses the `.env` file, just like the web app. If you've set the  'url' key in `config/app.php` to `env('APP_URL')`, and added the line `APP_URL=http://domain.local` to your `.env` file, it should be working fine (assuming your environment doesn't have $APP_URL already defined, which you said it didn't). Have you tried just setting the 'url' key to `http://domain.local` to see if that is working, at least?

Comment: I can't be 100% certain the `$APP_URL` is the problem, except running the statement in shell indicates it is not set.  However, I haven't tried that.  But I did just test it and I think I figured it out. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, I have accepted this as this cites the solution :)